# Curved text in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I curved my text widget in Flex?
I've got a circle surrounded by text and I'd need to create this style for the text. Also this circle takes 50% of the screen width so this curve effect should be dynamic as well

Comment: in short: you cannot, if you really want it you would need to draw letter by letter

Comment: That's way too much effort specially when this is going to be dynamic. I guess I would have to change my design. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class CurvedText extends StatelessWidget {
  const CurvedText({
    Key key,
    @required this.radius,
    @required this.text,
    @required this.textStyle,
    this.startAngle = 0,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double radius;
  final String text;
  final double startAngle;
  final TextStyle textStyle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => CustomPaint(
    painter: _Painter(
      radius,
      text,
      textStyle,
      initialAngle: startAngle,
    ),
  );
}

class _Painter extends CustomPainter {
  _Painter(this.radius, this.text, this.textStyle, {this.initialAngle = 0});

  final num radius;
  final String text;
  final double initialAngle;
  final TextStyle textStyle;

  final _textPainter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.translate(size.width / 2, size.height / 2 - radius);

    if (initialAngle != 0) {
      final d = 2 * radius * math.sin(initialAngle / 2);
      final rotationAngle = _calculateRotationAngle(0, initialAngle);
      canvas.rotate(rotationAngle);
      canvas.translate(d, 0);
    }

    double angle = initialAngle;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      angle = _drawLetter(canvas, text[i], angle);
    }
  }

  double _drawLetter(Canvas canvas, String letter, double prevAngle) {
    _textPainter.text = TextSpan(text: letter, style: textStyle);
    _textPainter.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: double.maxFinite,
    );

    final double d = _textPainter.width;
    final double alpha = 2 * math.asin(d / (2 * radius));

    final newAngle = _calculateRotationAngle(prevAngle, alpha);
    canvas.rotate(newAngle);

    _textPainter.paint(canvas, Offset(0, -_textPainter.height));
    canvas.translate(d, 0);

    return alpha;
  }

  double _calculateRotationAngle(double prevAngle, double alpha) =>
      (alpha + prevAngle) / 2;

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can look at this Flutter package. It might will help you little: [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_circular_text)

Comment: I think that's more for a complete circle. In my case I need like 4 different parts totally separated from each other. But looks really interesting tho and I probably will use it for some other projects. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the **EllipticText** widget included in the *elliptic_text* package. The widget lets you style the text as you please and comes with all the alignment options you'd want. See: https://pub.dev/packages/elliptic_text. Here's an example:

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 450.0,
  width: 300.0,
  child: EllipticText(
    text: "Smile! :) Why should text always be straight?",
    perimiterAlignment: EllipticText_PerimiterAlignment.bottom,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

for dart 2.12 and above

````
```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class CurvedText extends StatelessWidget {
  const CurvedText({
    super.key,
    required this.radius,
    required this.text,
    required this.textStyle,
    this.startAngle = 0,
  });

  final double radius;
  final String text;
  final double startAngle;
  final TextStyle textStyle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => CustomPaint(
        painter: _Painter(
          radius,
          text,
          textStyle,
          initialAngle: startAngle,
        ),
      );
}

class _Painter extends CustomPainter {
  _Painter(this.radius, this.text, this.textStyle, {this.initialAngle = 0});

  final num radius;
  final String text;
  final double initialAngle;
  final TextStyle textStyle;

  final _textPainter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.translate(size.width / 2, size.height / 2 - radius);

    if (initialAngle != 0) {
      final d = 2 * radius * math.sin(initialAngle / 2);
      final rotationAngle = _calculateRotationAngle(0, initialAngle);
      canvas.rotate(rotationAngle);
      canvas.translate(d, 0);
    }

    double angle = initialAngle;
    for (int i = 0; i 
      (alpha + prevAngle) / 2;

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```
````

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?